# Can you do aggregate functions among nearby geometry in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, aggregation

I want to do aggregation based not on group but on geometry, is that possible in PostGIS?

For example to calculate max, min, average price for all listings that's nearby a geometry point, how can I do something like:

```
select max(price), min(price), avg(price) 
from price_table 
where (ST_DWITHIN(geom_point, ST_SETSRID(ST_MAKEPOINT(-119.697321, 34.40592), 4326), 0.72))
```

If PostGIS doesn't have this feature, what other system should I look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work (have you tried it?)

PostgreSQL (the database software behind PostGIS) supports [many aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), which can also be modified to [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) (if you need that).

PostGIS has other aggregate functions, such as ST_Collect, ST_Extent and more, if you need them.

Comment: Ah I'm dumb. In my actual query I had some other field to select which cause the query doesn't work. Yes the sample query works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As Mike noted, your query should work fine.  are you having issue with it or is your question if you have a table of locations how to get the min, max, avg for the table points of interest (POI).

Assuming that is your question your query would look something like

```
SELECT  poi.gid,  poi.geom, max(price), min(price), avg(price) 
 FROM price_table INNER JOIN poi ON ST_DWithin(price_table.geom, poi.geom, 0.72)
  GROUP BY poi.gid, poi.geom;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. Yeah the query works, I was having other field in my actual query..